# Running task after only if another task is not up-to-date

Tags: gradle, build

I have a task that I want to run in gradle after the basic 'classes' task runs, but only if it was not UP-TO-DATE.

How can I model this in gradle?

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a wsgen task that I use to generate a wsdl file. The source that is used as a basis of the wsdl has changed, but the wsgen task still says it's up-to-date since the output file exists. I want to delete the wsdl file if the build/compile task ran and was not up-to-date.

Let's say I have my task as follows:

```
task deleteGeneratedWsdl() {
  // delete file here.
}

// I Only want this to run if classes was not UP-TO-DATE
deleteGeneratedWsdl.dependsOn classes
```

Here is my wsgen task:

```
task wsgen()  {
    def inputDir = file('build/classes/main')
    def dstDir = file('build/wsdl')
    def outputWsdl = file('build/wsdl/MyWSDL.wsdl')
    inputs.dir inputDir
    outputs.file outputWsdl
    doLast{
        dstDir.mkdirs()
        ant {
            taskdef(name:'wsgen',
                classname:'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen',
                classpath:configurations.jaxws.asPath)
            wsgen(keep:true,
                destdir: dstDir,
                genwsdl:'true',
                classpath:'build/classes/main;../UTIL_PROJ/build/classes/main',
                sei:'my.path.SourceFile')
        }
    }
}

wsgen.dependsOn classes
build.dependsOn wsgen
```

Comment: Could you explain why? I have a feeling you're asking the wrong question. Describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated the question to explain why i'm trying to do this.

Comment: The wsgen task should not be up-to-date if the file used as its source has changed. That's what you should fix. Show us the wsgen task. Make sure its inputs contain the source file it uses.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. I've added the wsgen task.

Comment: OK, I updated the inputDir to be file('src') rather than 'build/classes/main'. But, now I'm facing an issue where my wsimport task in another project indicates that it is Up-To-Date, despite that the wsdl source file was updated.

Comment: Then the wsimport task must, once again, incorrectly specify its inputs or task dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. The wsimport task had inputs.file wsdlSrc, which seemed to be causing it to think it was always up-to-date. Removing this gives me the desired behavior. I'd still like to know how to specify a task to run only if another task was not up-to-date.

Comment: A good example of when you might want to do this: 1) you have a task that updates a build number counter, 2) you want it to run before compile, 3) you only want it to run if the compile task isn't up-to-date